# Cron Error: No such file or directory

Tags: cron, wordpress, cpanel

Looking for some guidance around setting up a cron job to run every 15 minutes that sets off a script within the WordPress Plugin Amelia. According to their docs, I need to add the following line to the Cron file:

`*/15 * * * * https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpamelia_api&call=/notifications/scheduled/send`

Now as I'm using CPanel I set up the cronjob using the gui so it looks something like this. Swapping `https://domain.com` for the actual domain.:
[image]

I've added quotes to the command as I was getting errors because it was splitting the command when reaching an `&` but I am still getting an error saying the directory is not found.

Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An URL is not a command. Did you mean to call `curl` with this URL?

Comment: @Kusalananda not 100% sure as I'm trying to follow the documentation set out by the API. They mention no use of Curl. However willing to give it a try. I have tried `wget -q -O - https://mydomian.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpamelia_api&call=/notifications/scheduled/send` but no luck.

Comment: your wget command is without *"added quotes to the command as I was getting errors"*

Comment: Explain exactly what you wan the cron job to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating the command section to

```
GET 'https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpamelia_api&call=/notifications/scheduled/send' > /dev/null
```

You can try running the same command without `> /dev/null` , if the shell access is available.

Answer (score 0):

The [notifications documentation](https://wpamelia.com/notification-settings/) as available in July 2023 doesn't match what you were trying:

> Also, you can try this:
>
> ```
> */15 * * * * wget -q -O – "https://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpamelia_api&call=/notifications/scheduled/send"
> ```
>
> This:
>
> ```
> */15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php ~/public_html/wp-cron.php –action='wpamelia_api’ –call=’/notifications/scheduled/send'
> ```
>
> Or this:
>
> ```
> GET 'https://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpamelia_api&call=/notifications/scheduled/send' > /dev/null
> ```

Comparing the first suggestion with your own attempt, you appear to have omitted the command itself and the double quotes from the cron command line, `wget -q -O -`. (I had to replace the "smart quotes" in the documentation with standard single and double quote marks; perhaps that was your problem.)